# How do list most linked issues using either Jira advanced query or JQL

Tags: jira

I am trying to figure out a query where top 10 linked issues are returned. I know there is linkedIssues(issueKey,linkType) but it works on single issuekey for each call.

Is there a call similar like below, (soory that sql is not error proofed)

select issue.id from issue where linkedIssues(issue.id) order by linkedIssues(issue.id) desc?

Comment: What do you mean by "top 10 linked"? Do you mean the issues with the largest number of links?

Comment: It looks like that field (IssueLinksSystemField.java) can't be sorted on in the Issue Navigator. You could create a plugin with a custom field type that extends the system field.

Comment: yes it is like google page rank. we like to search only within mostly linked issue. currently we have so many history bugs and it is difficult for our support engineers to get relevant results. or we are thinking also to find out issues which have been commented most etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with SQL.  The table issuelink is a relationship table with 'source', 'destination', and 'linktype' columns.  The SQL query below would return all issues which have a destination link reference.

```
SELECT I.id, I.pkey, count(*) AS LinkCount 
FROM jiraissue I 
JOIN issuelink L on L.DESTINATION = I.ID
JOIN issuelinktype LT on LT.ID = L.LINKTYPE
WHERE LT.LINKNAME in ('Blocks', 'Cloners', 'Duplicate', 'Relates')
GROUP BY I.id, I.pkey
ORDER BY LinkCount DESC
```